# how to have 2 output of newman with single execution

Tags: postman, newman

Given the following scenario:

execute collections using newman, and save it in a reportfile but meanwhile also put the standard output of the the newman so that we can see in details. (like executing normally, without saving to any report file).

So my problem is when executing the newman with option save it to a reportfile, it seems redirecting the standard output and convert it to a report file. During this execution I see nothing in the standard output at all.

As of now I can do this in two step which seems a bit unprofessional.

inside of:
ExecutePostmanCollection.ps1
...
newman run $collection -e $env  --insecure -r junitfull --reporter-junitfull-export $result
...
newman run $collection -e $env  --insecure --disable-unicode | Out-File -FilePath "./output.txt"
Get-Content "./output.txt"

Thank you and
Regards
CP

Comment: You can use more than one reporter in a single command. For example, to get the junitfull and json outputs from the same run just add `-r junitfull,json`

Answer (score 0):

use cli reporter.

```
newman run $collection -e $env --insecure -r cli,junitfull --reporter-junitfull-export $result ...
newman run $collection -e $env --insecure -r cli --disable-unicode | Out-File -FilePath "./output.txt" Get-Content "./output.txt"
```